# Open Report manager from asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I need to open the ssrs report manager (not report viewer) from our asp.net application. For that , I created a hyperlink and the report manager opens perfectly in a new window. But every time it is prompting for credentials. I need to stop this. I can pass the credentials from the application. But I don't know how to pass ! Any thoughts ? The URL will be like this : http://SOME IP:81/Reports.
BTW,  we are using forms authentication on our .net app. Please let me know if anyone has inputs.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

By default SSRS uses Windows auth. You can change it to other modes, but if you're using forms auth in your app, I'm guessing you're using your own auth store?

It is possible to plug your own auth providers into SSRS, but you're going to have "fun" doing it. try this link for more help.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155029.aspx